# Appveyor. What are the default Postgres credentials?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-20.04, appveyor

Documentation for Windows [says](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/services-databases/#postgresql) that I may use user `postgres` with password `Password12!`. I found also [this](https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/20764-postgres-peer-authentication-failed) discussion, where they say: "We will fix both pg_hba.conf and password in next ubuntu image update." But it still doesn't work for me. I've also tried user `postgres` without password: no effect, the same authentication error.
Maybe I'm just blind or misunderstand something, here is my basic AppVeyor configuration:

```
version: 1.0.{build}
skip_tags: true
branches:
  only:
    - master
image: Ubuntu2004
services:
  - postgresql
environment:
  PGUSER: postgres
  PGPASSWORD: Password12!
build_script:
  - echo $PWD $USER $PGUSER $PGPASSWORD
  - sudo psql -U postgres -c 'create database my_test_db;'
```

and here is the error I get:

```
Starting 'services'
Starting PostgreSQL
Running "build_script" scripts
echo $PWD $USER $PGUSER $PGPASSWORD
/opt/appveyor/build-agent appveyor postgres Password12!
sudo psql -U postgres -c 'create database my_test_db;'
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
Command exited with code 2
Build failed
```

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: Add the `pg_hba.conf` file as update to your question. In meantime try: `sudo psql -U postgres -p 5432 -c 'create database my_test_db;'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found out a solution to my problem. As Adrian Klaver suggested in the comment under my post, I've checked `pg_hba.conf` file and found out that in the image Postgres is configured to use [peer authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-peer.html) Actually I've used the solution from [here](https://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/20764-postgres-peer-authentication-failed) and changed the authentication method to  trust. This configuration perfectly suits my needs. Here is the final `appveyor.yml` config:

```
version: 1.0.{build}
skip_tags: true
branches:
  only:
    - master
image: Ubuntu2004
services:
  - postgresql
environment:
  PGUSER: postgres
init:
  - sudo sed -i -E -e 's/(local\s+all\s+postgres\s+)peer/\1trust/' /etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf
build_script:
  - psql -U postgres -c 'create database my_test_db;'
```